# Are there infinitely many primes of the form $n^2 - d$, for any $d$ not a square?

Tags: number-theory

Clearly, for $d$ a square number, there is at most one prime of the form $n^2 - d$, since $n^2-d=(n+\sqrt d)(n-\sqrt d)$.

What about when $d$ is not a square number?

Comment: "Clearly, for $d$ a square number, there is only one prime..." - I don't see any primes for $d = 16$.

Comment: @TMM, updated to be "at most one prime"

Comment: It would be surprising if this were known. Nobody knows whether there are infinitely many primes $n^2 + 1$ and there is no resolution of the problem in sight.

Comment: See the answer to this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4506/are-there-infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-4n23

Comment: @Will, *everybody* knows that there are infinitely many primes of the form $n^2+1$, it's just that nobody knows how to *prove* it.

Comment: Is this not to mean that a norm from a quadratic extension is a prime? Of course there are infinitemy many, if $d$ is a negative square, hence not a square.

Comment: No, it would be easy otherwise. You are asking for the norm to be of a special form which isn't easily studied. Equivalently you are asking which primes factor in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ into the special form $(n+\sqrt{d})(n-\sqrt{d})$ for some $n$.

Answer (score 7):

There's a host of conjectures that assert that there an infinite number of primes of the form $n^2-d$ for fixed non-square $d$.  For example [Hardy and Littlewood's Conjecture F](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral#Hardy_and_Littlewood.27s_Conjecture_F), the [Bunyakovsky Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture), [Schinzel's Hypothesis H](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinzel%27s_hypothesis_H) and the [Bateman-Horn Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman%E2%80%93Horn_conjecture).

As given by [Shanks 1960](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1960-14-072/S0025-5718-1960-0120203-6/), a special case of Hardy and Littlewood's Conjecture F, related to this question, is as follows:

> **Conjecture**:  If $a$ is an integer which is not a
>   negative square, $a \neq -k^2$, and if $P_a(N)$ is the number of
>   primes of the form $n^2+a$ for $1 \leq n \leq N$, then \[P_a(N) \sim
>   \frac{1}{2} h_a \int_2^N \frac{dn}{\log n}\] where $h_a$ is the
>   infinite product \[h_a=\prod_{\text{prime } w \text{ does not divide
>   } a}^\infty \left(1-\left(\frac{-a}{w}\right) \frac{1}{w-1}\right)\] taken over
>   all odd primes, $w$, which do not divide $a$, and for which $(-a/w)$
>   is the [Legendre symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol).

The integral is (up to multiplicative/additive constants) the [logarithmic integral function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function).