# Primes of form $N^2 - 2$ where $N$ is odd and greater than $1$

Tags: number-theory

Let $S$ be the set of all odd numbers $N$  greater than $1$, and $f(N) =N^2 - 2$ for all $N$. Let $P$ be the subset of $S$ in which all members of  $P$ are primes. Prove that $P$ has infinitely many primes.

Comment: P should be all values of f(N) that are prime! Sorry bout that.

Comment: So you are simply asking "Prove that there are infinitely many primes of the form $N^2 - 2$."

Comment: @Bradford, it is best to edit the main question body (see the *edit* link under it) instead of explaining such a crucial point here in the comments.

Comment: Where is this problem coming from?

Comment: See the following:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144334/are-there-infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-n2-d-for-any-d-not-a-square

Comment: @kvmu I would even add that as a solution! With some extra text it would be more than adequate!

Answer (score 3):

This should be an open problem! Your problem is essentially prove that $N^2-2$ is prime infinitely often. This would be a special case of [Bunyakovsky conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture). If $N^2-2$ were not prime infinitely often, this would prove a counterexample to the conjecture (roughly speaking, it does not satisfy all the necessary conditions).