# Primes of the form $2n^2 + 2n + 1$

Tags: number-theory

Is it already known that there are infinitely many primes of the form $2n^2 + 2n + 1$?
I was searching online for any articles about it but I can't find any so I suppose this is still unknown. I found that there are infinitely many such primes and one result is that there are infinitely many primes of the form $4t_n + 1$ where $t_n$ are triangular numbers.

Comment: It might be worth noting that $2n^2+2n+1=n^2+(n+1)^2$ is the sum of two consecutive perfect squares.

Comment: Yes indeed that's how I actually found it first.

Comment: This paper claims that no polynomial of degree 2 or higher is known to represent infinitely many primes: https://math.byu.edu/~lzhao/Presentations/primequadprog1.pdf But not for a lack of 94 years of trying. So your result might be met with skepticism. Would you consider posting a clear argument?

Comment: Related MO topic: [Existence of polynomials of degree $\geq 2$ which represent infinitely many prime numbers](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/208614)

Comment: ok , yeah i got it

Comment: The proof is actually can be easily understood. I will try to post it here.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4506/are-there-infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-4n23), and the links at "Related".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely out-of-reach.
$$p=2x^2+2x+1\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad 2p-1 = (2x-1)^2 $$
hence you claim is equivalent to

> There are infinite values of $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n^2+1$ is
>   twice a prime

but

> There are infinite values of $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n^2+1$ is
>   a prime

is still a conjecture, namely [Landau's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_problems). The closest theorem we have at the moment is due to [Iwaniec and Friedlander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedlander%E2%80%93Iwaniec_theorem): there are an infinite number of primes of the form $a^2+b^4$.

Comment: there was indeed an error in my proof. I thought and assumed every primitive pythagorean triple is unique***