# Are there infinite many positive integers $n$ such that $n^2 + n +1$ is prime?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, quadratics, open-problem

I've heard that linear polynomials with proper integer coefficients has infinite many positive integers $n$ such that $f(n)$ is prime, by [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).

> But is there something done with general quadratics or this specific one $f(n)=n^2 +n+1$?

I tried to find some theorems which can be applied to this $f$ but I failed, and solving this problem directly
seems too difficult for me.

Comment: This is unknown , but the bunyakovsky-conjecture says "yes".

Comment: Research on the number of primes generated by a quadratic  goes back a long time, and very little is known. There are  many "innocent-sounding" Q's about $\Bbb N$ that are unanswered. One  is whether there exist $x,y,a,b\in \Bbb N$  with $a>1$ and $b>1,$ such that  $|x^a-y^b|=1,$  other than $\{x^a,y^b\}=\{3^2,2^3\}=\{9,8\}. $

Comment: @DanielWainfleet This conjecture (Catalan's conjecture) has been proven in the meantime. But for other differences , the problem is apparently still open.

Comment: @Peter . I had not known it was solved.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2003246/primes-of-the-form-2n2-2n-1/2003612#2003612

Comment: Related [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2700356/an-arithmetic-sequence-for-which-n2n1-is-prime).

Comment: Yes, some results are known https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem#Extensions_and_generalizations, but this is not enough for this case ...